# I see a blank GUI when I run code from PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt5, qt-designer, loadui

I designed a GUI using QtDesigner and when I run it using `Ctrl+R` I see a result like I expected.

[image: result]

When I import this GUI using `ui.loadUi()` in PyCharm and run the code,

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

class loadUi_example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        loadUi("view.ui", self)

app = QApplication([])
window = loadUi_example()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

I see a blank page.

[image: Blank page]

My PyQt version is 5.14.1. And this is my [GUI](https://easyupload.io/u4dgsu) file.

Comment: Hello! And what is your result when you start your program from a command-line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to inherit from QMainWindow, instead you should inherit from QWidget:

```
class loadUi_example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        loadUi("view.ui", self)
```

This solves your problem.